# Can you run anything during app screen launch?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to run a background task while `LaunchScreen.storyboard` is showing?

Comment: Your question should be updated to clearly indicate what it is that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest you can run code is in `main` or the `init` of your `UIApplicationDelegate`. The launch screen is shown before either of those and it is shown briefly while those are called until your app's root view controller is displayed by the time the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate completes.

So yes, you can start some code on a background queue just before your app transitions from showing the launch screen to showing the root controller.

Comment: So I can run when launch screen is ending but not when it is starting, correct?

Comment: Right. iOS shows your launch screen when the user taps the app icon. This is presented as the app is being loaded into memory all before the 1st line of code can possibly be run. This is why a launch screen storyboard is static and can't make use of any code or a custom view controller. In fact, iOS actually generates a static image from your launch screen storyboard and that image is what is displayed initially.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you create a StoryBoard, make it a initial view controller instead of **LaunchScreen.storyboard** and set your logic in that initial view controller file. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use after the `LaunchScreen` a `Splashscreen` that will be responsible for doing the actual transition to the main `ViewController` once all the "bootstrapping" phase is complete?

`LaunchScreen > Splashscreen (same layout as previously) > Main`

Wouldn't that fit your need?